# Can't get AmazonS3Client object in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to get AmazonS3Client object in java. Following is my code.

```
logger.info("getS3Client starting...");
        logger.info("awsUser() : " + awsUser());
        logger.info("awsSecret() : " + awsSecret());
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsUser(), awsSecret());
        logger.info("credentials : " + credentials);
        if(credentials != null) {
            logger.info("credentials.aswuser : " + credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
            logger.info("credentials.awssecret id : " + credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
        }
        AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
        logger.info("aws client : " + client);
```

It prints all the logs until it invokes AmazonS3Client constructor. After that nothing happens (no logs get printed). Can't debug this in Beta environment. Only solution is putting logs. This works in local environment btw without any issue.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: Did you try using the S3 client to perform any operations? Did that fail?

Comment: How are you handling exceptions? Usually, if you do something and don't see a subsequent log message, it's an indication that an exception was thrown. Do you catch and log those exceptions, or simply discard them?

Comment: @ChackoMathew Yes. After getting the S3Client I will be doing some operations with that. In local environment it works. In beta environment it's not. That's what baffles me.

Comment: @kdgregory Ya. This code is in a try catch block. At least it should throw "some" exception. But it just do nothing. Just no logs. nothing!!

Comment: In that case I'm not sure what to tell you. I would suspect running on a private subnet in a VPC without NAT or S3 endpoint, but (1) as far as I know (and I just checked the source) the S3 client doesn't attempt a network connection in its constructor, and (2) that would eventually time-out and cause an exception.

Comment: You can probably gain some insight by triggering a thread-dump when it apparently hangs. I realize that you say you're in a beta environment, but you should be able to work with your ops people to bring up a new machine in that environment for testing (if not, then you need to have a discussion with your manager about how they're impacting your ability to do your job).

Comment: One other comment: that `(credentials != null)` test is suspicious: you're calling `new`, so either you're going to get a not-null object or you're going to throw. So why the test?

Answer (score 0):

The s3 jar needs a later version of slf4j-api dependency for its logging. A static call is made to the logger. The standalone code would have downloaded the latest dependency. However, when integrating the existing application, the earlier version of the jar would have been taken up. This is a question asked 2 years ago. However,I found this when I faced the same issue. Dropping the answer here as it might help another developer.